# IF else statement for calculating max heart rate

Tags: java

need output to print

**Your max heart rate is 191.5 beats per minute.**

the number is will change due to the equation trying to be added.

so far this is the problem Im stuck on.

```
System.out.print("Your max heart rate is ");

if (gender == 1) { //calculate female heart rate

}  else {//calculate male heart rate

}

System.out.println(maxHeartRate + "beats per minute.");

// Max heart rate for females:
209 - (0.7 * ageInYears)

// Max heart rate for males:
214 - (0.8 * ageInYears)
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args)  {

      String name = "";
      int ageInYears = 0;
      int gender = 0;
      double maxHeartRate = 0;

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
      //Prompt the user for thier name:
      System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
      name = userInput.nextLine();

      //Prompt the user for their age:
      System.out.print("Enter your age in years: ");
      ageInYears = userInput.nextInt();

      //Prompt the user to enter gender:
      System.out.print("Enter your gender(1 for female and 0 for male): ");
      gender = userInput.nextInt();

      //convert age:
      System.out.println("\tYour age in minutes is "
         + ageInYears * 525600 + "minutes.");

      System.out.println("\tYour age in centuries is "
         + (double) ageInYears / 100 + "centuries.");

      // display max heart rate
      System.out.print("Your max heart rate is ");


   }
}
```

this is the entire exercise that I have compiled so far. The If else is where Im getting hung up everytime my code is errors out for If else statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all the pieces, you just have to assembly them:

```cs
// Your previous code

// Calculate max heart rate
if (gender == 1)
    maxHeartRate = 209 - (0.7 * ageInYears);
else
    maxHeartRate = 214 - (0.8 * ageInYears);

// Then simply print it
System.out.print("Your max heart rate is " + maxHeartRate);
```

Comment: Thank you!,brand new to coding was just assembling the statement wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```java
// Max heart rate for females:
if (gender ==1) {
    maxHeartRate = 209 - (0.7 * ageInYears);
else {
// Max heart rate for males:
    maxHeartRate = 214 - (0.8 * ageInYears);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
if (gender == 1)
    maxHeartRate = 209 - (0.7 * ageInYears);
else
    maxHeartRate = 214 - (0.8 * ageInYears);


System.out.println(String.format("Your max heart rate is %s beats per minute.",maxHeartRate));
```

Comment: How does this fix their issue at all?  You do not calculate the `maxHeartRate` at all here.  And using `String.format` inside of `System.out.print` is redundant, you might as well use `System.out.printf` or `System.out.format`, so it is bad advice too.